# Laravel grab values from another table

Tags: string, laravel, foreach

I am using the below code in my controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $playlist = Playlists::find($id); //Grab the playlist data from the database

    $tracks = explode(', ',$playlist->tracks); //Seperate the track id's (remove the comma) -> In database it is stored like this: 54, 23, 45, 23, 23 etc..

    $showTracks = array(); //Create a new array

    foreach ($tracks as $track)
    {
        $showTracks[] = Tracks::where('id', '=', $track); //Grab the actual names of the tracks
    }

    return View::make('playlists/show')
    ->with('tracks', $showTracks);
}
```

What I have is the following. A database table called "Tracks" and a table called "Playlists". All tracks have a field called "name" in which the full name of a song is listed. In my playlists table I have a field called "tracks" in which all tracks that belong to that playlist are stored using the id's of the tracks, comma seperated, like below:

23, 45, 22, 12, 543 .. and so on

Now what I want to do is, when I go to mysite.com/playlists/1 (to call the show function) - I want all tracks to be displayed by their name, using a foreach, in my blade view:

```
@foreach ($tracks as $track)
{{ $track }}
@endforeach
```

But with my current function I am getting the following error:

Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

And if I do this:

```
@foreach ($tracks as $track)
{{ $track->name }}
@endforeach
```

It shows this error:

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$name

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out where I might go wrong..

Comment: You should change your database schema. Having comma seperated values in the databse is almost allways a bad idea. You could eager load this query very very easy if you had a correct table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$showTracks[] = Tracks::where('id', '=', $track)->first();
```

You need to actually execute the query by calling first(), which will retrieve the first result from that query. Since you are querying by id, there should only be one. Alternatively, you can use Tracks::find($track) and get the same results.

That said, michael is correct in the comments up there that this is not the best way to set up your schema. Preferred would be to use a pivot table, and then set up model relationships, which would allow you to write your code like this:

```
$playlist = Playlists::find($id);
return View::make('playlists/show')->with('playlist', $playlist);
```

And then in your view:

```
@foreach($playlist->tracks as $track)
{{ $track->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Although I am aware of the model relationships (I even already have them set up), I wouldn't know how my actual database structure should look like and how I would link tracks to my playlists?

Comment: That gets a little involved to explain. Basically you would have three tables. playlists (id, name), tracks (id, name), and playlist_tracks (playlist_id, track_id). When adding a track to a playlist, you would create a new row in the playlist_tracks table with the appropriate playlist_id and track_id. So every song in a playlist would be a new row in the playlist_tracks table.

Check these for more reference: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Ah alright, thanks for the info. That is actually what I was trying to avoid (I had that) and I wanted to keep it simple for my own sake (it's for my personal site just for me alone :))

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation though and thanks for the help!